# Why long long and int multiplication produces overflow?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I am testing this piece of code in c

```
  long long n = 1000000;
  long long var1,var2;
  int x = 50000;
  var1 = n * x * x;
  var2 = x * x * n;
  printf("var1 = %lld\n", var1);
  printf("var2 = %lld\n", var2);
```

When i run it produces this output

```
var1 = 2500000000000000
var2 = -1794967296000000
```

I don't understand why changing the order of variables being multiplied produced an overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case associativity is left to right, so what happens is:

```
  var1 = (n * x) * x;
  var2 = (x * x) * n;
```

In case of `n * x`, the `x` will be converted to `long long` since `n` is `long long`, so it has a higher conversion rank. Therefore, this partial result will not overflow.

But with `x * x`, both operands are `int` therefore the result will be `int` as well, and that can't hold the value `2,500,000,000`, which causes the overflow.